# Error:scala: 'jvm-1.8' is not a valid choice for '-target' in sbt project

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, jvm, sbt

I have a scala,sbt project to run and getting the exception below. Tried to find the solution on internet, only gradle related solutions were available.

> Error:scala: 'jvm-1.8' is not a valid choice for '-target'
>
> Error:scala: bad option: '-target:jvm-1.8'

I tried changing the compiler config and other intellij idea settings but unsuccessful to get rid of this issue.
What is missing here ?

Attached the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the setting you are missing in SBT (added in build.sbt):

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-target", "1.8")
```

Comment: It is already there in my build.sbt. Still the issue persists @marios

Comment: can you show me that section of your build.sbt file?

Comment: scalacOptions ++= Seq(
        "-target:jvm-1.8",
        "-language:postfixOps",
        //"-optimize",
        "-deprecation"
    )

Comment: well kind sir, see what I have in the answer and what you just typed here, they ain't the same. there is no "jvm" and they are two parts separated by a comma.

Comment: finally that's not a scalacOption,it's a javacOption.

Comment: Yes it was different and I added the above and refreshed sbt, still the same :-(

Comment: Close and reopen IntelliJ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144218/discussion-between-jet-and-marios).

Comment: Note that you need Scala 2.11 and newer for Java 1.8

Comment: do you still have issues?

Comment: I just deleted the source code and cloned again, after coming to know it was working in other machines, I don't see that problem now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

encountered same issue with gradle. turns out need to update gradle to latest version. you might would like to try same for SBT.